# React addEventListener having issues when the page rerenders

Tags: javascript, reactjs, addeventlistener

I have put together a infinite scroll to load more items when a user reaches the bottom of the screen. It works fine the first time but for some reason the eventListener seems to disappear when the first nextLink from redux is loaded.

My code:

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

import * as teamsActions from "../../store/teams/actions";
import TeamCard from "../../common/teamCard/teamCard";
import ReactAI from "react-appinsights";
import WithLoading from "../../common/utils/withLoading";
import {
    objectToArray,
    sortArray
} from "../../assets/general_functions/objectsAndArrays";
import { faRubleSign } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

class TeamsContainer extends Component {
    _isMounted = false;
    state = {
        scrolling: false
    };
componentDidMount() {
    this._isMounted = true;
    this.props.onFetchTeams();

    this.scrollListener = window.addEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll);
}
s;

componentWillUnmount() {
    this._isMounted = false;
    window.removeEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll);
}

loadTeams = () => {
    console.log("is teams loading?", this.props.loading);
    if (this.props.loading === false) {
        console.log("What is the nextLink", this.props.teams["@odata.nextLink"]);
        this.props.onFetchMoreTeams(this.props.teams["@odata.nextLink"]);
    }
};

loadMore = () => {
    this.setState(
        {
            scrolling: true
        },
        this.loadTeams
    );
};

handleScroll = () => {
    const { scrolling } = this.state;

    if (scrolling) return;
    if (
        typeof this.props.teams.value !== "undefined" ||
        this.props.teams.value > 0
    ) {
        console.log("value", this.props.teams.value);

        const lastTeam = document.querySelector(
            ".team-card-wrapper:last-of-type"
        );

        // get the height of the current team, and get the height of the current position on screen.
        const lastTeamOffset = lastTeam.offsetTop + lastTeam.clientHeight;
        const pageOffset = window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight;
        const bottomOffset = 30;

        if (pageOffset > lastTeamOffset - bottomOffset) {
            this.loadMore();
        }
    }
};

render() {
    let loading = "";
    let error = "";
    let teams = [];
    let delay = 0;
    let loadMoreButton = "";

    // check whether the component is fetching data
    let loader = "";
    if (this.props.teamsLoading) {
        loader = <WithLoading isLoading={true} />;
    }

    // check if there was an error
    this.props.error && this.props.loading === false
        ? (error = <p>There was an error</p>)
        : (error = "");

    // reorder the teams and make teamCards of it.
    if (this.props.teams["value"]) {
        // convert the teams object to an array of objects.
        // order it by sequence property.
        teams = this.props.teams.value;
        teams = objectToArray(this.props.teams["value"]);
        teams = teams.sort(sortArray("sequence")).reverse();

        teams = teams.map(team => {


            if (delay === 300) {
                    delay = 0;
                }
                delay = delay + 75;

                return (
                    <TeamCard
                        delay={delay}
                        id={team.id}
                        title={team.title}
                        description={team.description}
                        isFavorite={team.isFavorite}
                        memberCount={team.memberCount}
                        key={team.id}
                    />
                );
            });
        } else {
            teams = loader = <WithLoading isLoading={true} />;
        }
        // this.props.teams["value"]);

        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <div className="App">
                    {loader == "" ? (
                        <div className="team-cards-wrapper">{teams}</div>
                    ) : (
                        <div>{loader}</div>
                    )}
                </div>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        error: state.teamsSlice.teamsError,
        loading: state.teamsSlice.teamsLoading,
        teams: state.teamsSlice.teams,
        searchTerm: state.teamsSlice.searchTerm
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        onFetchTeams: () => dispatch(teamsActions.fetchTeams()),
        onFetchMoreTeams: teamsNextLink =>
            dispatch(teamsActions.fetchMoreTeams(teamsNextLink))
    };
};

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(ReactAI.withTracking(TeamsContainer));
```

My console (The value is printed on scroll. after loading it, it doesnt echo any value anymore):

[image]

Event handlers according to the console:
[image]

Redux store:
[image]

Edit:

I found that there was a problem in the state.scrolling. It's set to true but never reset after the data has loaded.

any help is much appreciated! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I think because you are having two componentWillUnMount. and this line

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", e => {
    this.handleScroll(e);
});
```

seems to be a little wrong. it maybe window.addEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll) only
- second thing is that I think you should use debounce on scroll event so it can be better for performance

Comment: I didn't see the double unmount, I merged the statements into 1. It doesn't resolve the issue though. Debounce will definitely add but for now I am only focusing on this problem. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the problem was setting the scrolling state back to false.

After fetching more redux items, i decided to use a timeout to debounce incoming similar api requests.

```
setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({ scrolling: false });
        }, 300);
```